# How to listen to a port(69) of a server using the TFTP session in java?

Tags: java, tftp

I want to get a file thrown by the client using the TFTP session. I mean the TFTP session has to listen to the port continuously and catch the file that was thrown from the client.

I have googled it and couldn't find any library except "package org.apache.commons.net.tftp". In this library I can able to find the methods for transferring the file from server from TFTP session and placing it in users PC and vice versa. but could not able to receive the file which is thrown by the client to the server.

Manually i can achieve this by starting the "pumpkin" as the tftp server and accept the file thrown by the client up on receiving the file through tftp session.where pumpkin will acts like a server on my system.

I can find the python library for the same it's "TFTPY".Can any one help me in doing this in java.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the way to solve my problem in the following link.
                      http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/testapidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPServer.html. Thanks all.